# Question about RFID Reader Frequency and RFID Tags

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, frequency, rfid

I'm researching about RFID Technology as i'm trying to build a RFID Reader using an Arduino and/or Raspberry Pi which i been trying to do so for a month however with no avail. So i been reading up as much as i can however i can't seem to find a proper answer.

There're 3 frequency ranges 125KHz (LF), 13.56MHz (HF) and 900MHz (UHF) for RFID Tags 
Than there're different readers but for example 'Grove - 125KHz RFID Reader'

**Question**

1. The reader mentioned about 125KHz, so does that mean it can only read 125KHz Tags? Or can it also read the higher frequencies?
2. What if i purchase a 900MHz(UHF) Reader, will that read only 900MHz tags? or all the others?
3. SAlso i'm confused about RFID and Mifare. All the boards such as 'RFID-RC522' and 'PN532' boards says to read RFID but their codes only read MiFares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFID is a generic term for the technology, like Wireless, Stereo, Fuel Injection...

Mifare is a Philips brand name for a particular 13.56 MHz system.
At 13 MHz, read carefully about what tags the reader will read. There are a few types, ISO14443 specifies one standard.

Systems for one frequency cannot do other frequencies, everything about the reader is built around the frequency choice.
(There might be dual-band 125/13.56 systems, then they would work with both specified bands.)